# Google Map Color Coding Countries based on marker value

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

I need to color code counties on my google maps based on the markers on these locations. Anyone with some idea as to how this can be done? I am using [google earth](http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/helloearth/index.html)

I can create markers dynamically and show my data. Now I need to find a way to style google maps.

Comment: You mean each country's outline, or a colour code on the marker?

Comment: I wanted every country to have a different shade based on existence of data on it. Much like what the geomaps offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of right now Google does not support county shading it seems. With map charts here, it lets you shade countries and states.

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/gallery/new_map_charts.html

The closest I've got to seeing county shading is an example here:

http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&hl=en&q=http://lazylightning.org/mncounties-sorted.kmz&ie=UTF8&z=6&om=1

You can read a little bit about how it was made here:
http://www.lazylightning.org/minnesota-county-kmz-overlay-for-google-maps

Other links that you might find useful:
http://nationalatlas.gov/atlasftp.html?openChapters=chpbound#chpbound

http://freegeographytools.com/2007/converting-e00-vector-data-to-shapefiles-a-free-and-fairly-painless-approach

http://www.zonums.com/shp2kml.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how extensively you can customize Google Earth, but if you're not dead-set on it, try one of these: [Google Visualizations](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery.html)

Depending on which one you choose (I believe there are three different types of maps available,) there are loads of customization possibilities. Also, none of these require a proprietary plugin like Google Earth does (just Javascript and Flash. Okay, Flash is a proprietary plugin, but I'm sure it's far more common than the Google Earth plugin.)

Comment: I needed a the grobe rotating but this is a very good pointer too. How can I have different colors for those in this section? I am using the geomap?

Comment: [Configuration options](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/geomap.html#Configuration_Options) on the Geomap page shows you how to set the gradient colors, and in turn, the country/region colors.